# How do I create a Django web application with an HTML/CSS/JS frontend and a Django and Flask backend?

Tags: python, django

I have never made a web application using the combination of Django, Python, and Flask. I am not sure how to even get the directory sorted out. I was going to just write the front end in HTML/CSS/JS and then figure out how to connect everything to it, but I don't even know where to begin. Here is the prompt:

> Build a Django application that will connect with 3 external weather
>   services and provide an average temperature for a given zip lat/lon.
>   The Django application should have a single url route that takes in a
>   latitude, longitude, and a list of external services to filter on. 
>   The acceptable filters will be ‘noaa’, ‘weather.com’, and
>   ‘accuweather’.
>
> For example: if the user sends in ‘noaa’ and ‘accuweather’ in the
>   filter list, then only those two services will be used to calculate
>   the average temperature for the given lat/lon.
>
> In order to connect with the 3 external APIs, we have created a simple
>   Flask application that you will run and connect to.  This will prevent
>   you from having to actually integrate with three external providers.
>   Please access this application and view the readme
>   here: https://github.com/otterlogic/mock-weather-api
>
> Although this is a simple application, please use architecture and
>   design patterns as you would for a larger and more complex project.
>
> Guidelines:
>
> Use Django
>
> Create a url route that accepts: latitude, longitude, and filters
>
> Filter the external providers depending on the user input filters
>
> The response to the request will be a json response with the average
>   current temperature

I always have trouble getting started when there's already existing code. I do so much better when I am the one creating everything from scratch. Does anyone else usually have this problem?

Comment: I would argue that the vast majority of programming is about using code you *didn't* write. Mastering that is of utmost importance. That said, have you gone through any of the Django tutorials on the web? There are plenty of them, many of which are real nice (the [official documentation](https://www.djangoproject.com/start/) is a great place to start).

Comment: I spent all day yesterday going through Django tutorials. I just wasn't sure how the flask portion fit into my directory or the Django portion and how the web form fit into all those. I just need some clarification

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the instructions:

```
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
FLASK_APP=app.py 
flask run
```

You can do without a virtualenv but you're gonna need Python and pip installed. Assuming you got Python installed, you also need to be able to run pip so that you can install the dependencies. If you still cannot start Flask after doing that, you should check that the python scripts are in your system PATH variable.

Then you just follow the Flask routing scheme and use Django as a backend for your weather service. The application logic is not that large.

Comment: I was able to get the flask app running without any problems whatsoever. It was super easy. I just hit a wall after that